# How can I parse query strings in actix-web?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

How can I parse the `name` and `color` arguments from the following URL using [actix-web](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.18/actix_web/)?

```
http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple
```

I suppose my path should be `/path/to/page` and then when I try to query for `name` I receive an empty string (`req.match_info().query("name")` where `req: &HttpRequest`).

The only [documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.1.0/actix_web/struct.Params.html) I found is about matching names (e.g., if the path is `/people/{page}/` it'll match `/people/123/` such that `page = 123` but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 34):

It looks like they removed the `query` function and just have a `query_string` function. You could use a crate for this called [qstring](https://crates.io/crates/qstring):

```
use qstring::QString;
...
let query_str = req.query_string(); // "name=ferret"
let qs = QString::from(query_str);
let name = qs.get("name").unwrap(); // "ferret"
```

You could also use an [extractor](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/) to deserialize the query params into a struct with Serde

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Info {
    username: String,
}

fn index(info: web::Query<Info>) -> Result<String, actix_web::Error> {
    Ok(format!("Welcome {}!", info.username))
}
```

Note that the handler will only be called if the query `username` is actually present in the request. This would call the handler:

`curl "http://localhost:5000?username=joe"`

but these would not:

```
curl "http://localhost:5000"
curl "http://localhost:5000?password=blah"
```

If you need optional parameters, just make the properties in your struct `Option`s.

```
username: Option<String>
```

You can also use multiple `web::Query<SomeType>` parameters in a handler.

Comment: It cannot parse array. For example, `a=1&a=2` should be parsed into `[1, 2]` but you can only get 1

Answer (score 10):

`actix_web::web::query` parses query strings:

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App};
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Params {
    name: String,
    color: String,
}

#[get("/path/to/page")]
async fn handler(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let params = web::Query::<Params>::from_query(req.query_string()).unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("{:?}", params))
}
```

[The official documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Query.html) has another example.

Comment: helpful example! note that you can then access attributes of `params` like `params.name` or `&params.name`

Answer (score 3):

> This is for actix-web v0.7

I managed to get it work by using:

```
let name = req.query().get("name").unwrap(); // name = "ferret"
```

Comment: Did this change in a recent version? On Actix Web 1.0.7, I am getting `error[E0599]: no method named `query` found for type `actix_web::request::HttpRequest` in the current scope`

Answer (score 1):

If you need default query parameters you can define them with the following code:

```rust
use actix_web::{App, get, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, web, HttpRequest};

...

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Params {
    orgIds: String
}

...

async fn totd(db_pool: web::Data<Pool>, req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    let params = web::Query::<Params>::from_query(req.query_string())
        .unwrap_or(web::Query(Params { orgIds: String::from("2") }));
    let org_ids = &params.orgIds;
...
```

This applies to `actix-web = "4"`

Alternatively you can also use `Query::<HashMap<String, String>>::from_query` to parse the query.

Here is an example using `from_query`:

```rust
let params = Query::<HashMap<String, String>>::from_query(req.query_string())
        .unwrap();
let default_org_id = &String::from("2");
let default_lang = &String::from("en");
let org_ids = params.get("orgIds").unwrap_or(default_org_id);
let lang = params.get("lang").unwrap_or(default_lang);
```

With this second technique it is easier to deal with default values.